# Unable to fill Values in Pandas DataFrame using ffill method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to fill the Blank cells in Dataframe Using pandas ffill method but unable to fill Year column in the Dataframe.

```
Year            month
1947             M11
                 M11
1947             M12
                 M12
1948             M01
                 M01
```

I tried

```
Data['Year'] = Data['Year'].ffill(axis = 0)              
Data['month'] = Data['month'].ffill(axis = 0)
```

for Month column ffill method worked, but for Year column it is not working , please help.

My final required output should be like this

```
Year            month
1947             M11
1947             M11
1947             M12
1947             M12
1948             M01
1948             M01
```

Comment: Try `Data = Data.reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael  This didnt work in my case

Comment: Can you check another dupe?